# How can I do a reverse grep using Perl?

Tags: perl, grep

What is the equivalent of `grep -v` in Perl?

The code looks like this

```
@files = reversegrep(/^[ ]+$/, @files);
```

I want `@files` to have a list of all the file names that are not empty.

Comment: What does `/^[ ]+$/` have to do with files being empty?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use negation in the expression or block:

```
@files = grep !/^\s+$/, @files;
```

See [perldoc grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).